# Issues with TCP protocol in Python (3.8.0) after generating the exe with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, tcp, pyinstaller, scapy

I'm using raw socket and Scapy to create a basic sniffer, when i run the script from PyCharm (on the left of the image) it seems to work properly, but if i run it from the exe (created with Pyinstaller, on right of the image) it seems to capture only outgoing packets with TCP protocol.

UDP, ICMP and IGMP don't have this issue.

My local IPv4 is `192.168.1.7`

[image: PyCharm - Pyinstaller exe]

I'm using the follow code to get information about the packet:

```
def sniff():
    global s, tcp, udp, icmp, all_proto, table, IPN

    to_show = {'TCP':tcp.get(), 'UDP':udp.get(), 'ICMP':icmp.get()}
    show_all = all_proto.get()

    if not show_all and not 1 in to_show.values():
        showerror('MyProgram', 'No protocol(s) selected!')
        return

    # the public network interface
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

    # create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    s.bind((HOST, 0))

    # Include IP headers
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

    # receive all packages
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

    while True:
        # receive a package
        try:
            data = s.recvfrom(65565)
        except:
            break

        t = time.ctime().split()[3]
        packet = IP(data[0])

        try:
            proto = IPN[str(packet.proto)]
        except:
            proto = '-'
        try:
            src = packet.src
        except:
            src = '-'
        try:
            dst = packet.dst
        except:
            dst = '-'
        try:
            sport = packet.sport
        except:
            sport = '-'
        try:
            dport = packet.dport
        except:
            dport = '-'
        try:
            data = packet.load
        except:
            data = data[0][20:] # maybe is there the issue? I'm not sure about this line


        if show_all:
            table.insert("", END, tags=proto, values=(t, proto, src, dst, sport, dport, data))
        else:
            try:
                if to_show[proto]:
                    table.insert("", END, tags=proto, values=(t, proto, src, dst, sport, dport, data))
            except:
                pass

        table.yview_moveto(1) # set view to last row
```

IP() is the function of scapy.all.

The GUI is made with Tkinter.

In Pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico --uac-admin script.py
```

So, why does the program work differently after creating the exe with Pyinstaller?

**EDIT:**

I removed the `--windowed` option from Pyinstaller to check for exceptions as suggested by @jizhihaoSAMA.

Result:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
```

I specify that I receive this warning only when the program is just open and not during its execution.

Comment: Try to remove `--windowed` to see the raised exception.(There are also some bugs if you don't use console window.)

Comment: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__) i have this warning when i start the program even if i didn't import matplotlib

Comment: @Marino this is a known bug which I'm working on fixing. Ignore this warning for now; just don't upgrade matplotlib to matplotlib 3.3. Matplotlib is probably a dependency of one of the libraries you are using.

Comment: @Legorooj, do you think this bug could compromise the correct working of the exe?
I specify that I receive this warning only when the program is just open and not during its execution. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Marino no, it won't affect your program as long as you don't upgrade matplotlib to 3.3+